# Why can't I find my static folder in my project

Tags: django

I'm working on a Django project and I can't see my static folder, I'm also having a problem displaying images.

And when I inspect the image div in the src it's written unknown, Here's how I display the image from the admin

```
``<img class="rounded-circle account-profile" src="{{ user.Profile.profile_photo.url }}" alt="profile">``
```

User is the current user, the profile and then the name of the column.

My folder structure is route-folder( **project-folder**, **media-folder** and **app-folder** )

My static settings

````
```STATIC_URL = '/static/'
SITE_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, "static/"),
]```
````

The Url:
    `if settings.DEBUG:
        urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)`

Comment: I just can't locate the static folder in my project

Comment: Have I messed somewhere?!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to retrieve a media image not a static one.  I recomend using Whitenoise package to serve static files.

Follow instruction in this tutorial: http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html

Check you have all this setup:

```
# Settings

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")

STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)
```

In the templates, you should remember to add the `{% load static %}` to grant access to the actual files.

Comment: I've tried it and my images are still not displaying. And I also don't have the static folder in my application, once I create the app it should automatically generate a static folder, right??

Comment: I have created a static folder and added CSS file which is working properly but I'm still unable to display the image.